# how to iterate over files in neighbouring dir

Tags: python

I have a project structure like this

```
test/foo.py
test/bar (directory with 10 files)
src/
README.MD
```

From `foo.py` (which is in `test` dir), I wish to iterate over the 10 files in the `bar` dir (which is also in `test` dir). I tried to do this

```
import os

for path in os.listdir('bar'):
    etc
```

But it says, "no such file or directory: bar"

I then tried to do this

```
basepath = '/Users/me/pythonprojects/project_x/bar' 
for path in os.listdir(basepath):
    etc
```

However, when I counted over the number of files it iterated over, it was 0 (Not the expected 10).

I then tried to do this

```
   for path in '/Users/me/pythonprojects/project_x/test/bar':
       etc
```

However, it then iterated over every file in my system (hundreds, not just the 10 in bar).

Although this is not what I wish to do, if from the command line I pass an argument of `.` to sys.argv[1] and then try to iterate over the bar dir like this

```
for path in sys.argv[1]
```

It iterates over the ten files in the bar dir.

So, is there a way from `foo.py` to iterate over the files in `bar` (and only the files in `bar` dir)

Update, when I do `print(os.getcwd(), "foo.py cwd")` in `foo.py` (and then call the test runner from `run_test.py` in root), it says

```
/Users/me/pythonprojects/project_x
```

i.e. `os.getcwd()` doesn't recognize that `foo.py` is in `test` dir of the project, which may be because the test is run from root?

Comment: are you sure you executed `foo.py` in the right directory context? try printing `os.getcwd()` in `foo.py`

Comment: I updated the OP with that information and other related relevant info, namely that it's in a test dir. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use functions in `os.path` to do this (works only from a script, not REPL):

```
import os

# retrieve path to directory with script
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

bar_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'bar')

for f in os.listdir(bar_dir):
    print(f)
```

Comment: Tried your solution thank you but it's still iterating over 0 files. Probably my fault as I might have left out some key information. Updated OP if you have time.

Comment: ignore my comment.